# Polymer preferred terminology component or element

Tags: polymer

I'm looking at the Polymer js documentation and I notice some discrepancy. The terms "component" and "element" seem to be used interchangeably. Are they the same or is there a difference? If there is a difference, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Polymer is for building custom elements where "element" refers to HTML tags (like `<input>` element, `<h1>` element. For Polymer "element" is the preferred term but "component" means the same.
See also https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like what I assumed.